# beanFactory.getBean not loading bean

Tags: spring

I am having a service class annotated with @Service annotation as Class A and I am implementing BeanFactoryAware in A. Now I am setting the BeanFactory using setBeanFactory method. I am trying to load a bean "B" using beanFactory.getBean method. Now in this case is it compulsory to define "B" bean in application-context.xml file?

Answer (score 2):

If you inject the `BeanFactory` in class A, and then try to get bean `b` with `beanFactory.getBean`, bean `b` **must** be declared in the same application context as bean `a`, or in a parent of this application context.

Concrete use cases for a standard web application with a root application context and a servlet application context for a `DispatcherServlet` :

- if `A` in is root application context, `B` **must** be declared in root application context
- if `A` in is servlet application context, `B` can be declared either in servlet application context or in root one

But if the only reason of that is to use bean `B` in bean `A` it would be better to directly inject it instead of the `BeanFactory` (with same rules for the application contextes)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways ..

**first one**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="b" class="your.package.B" />

</beans>
```

**second one**

Spring will scan this folder and find out the bean (annotated with @Component, @Service, @Repository, etc) and register it

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="your.package" />

</beans>
```

I suggest to use..

```
public class Application implements ApplicationContextAware{

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)throws BeansException    {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

}
```

and the method

```
B b = applicationContext.getBean("b");
```